# Variables y bucles for en Java

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de contar cuantos números del que yo quiero tiene una array. Es decir, que si le pido que me cuente los cuatros que hay, me devuelva el número de cuatros que hay en el array. Cuando hago la prueba me pone el número de la variable `contador` como si no se hubiera contado en el bucle `for`. Me imagino que es una tontería pero he probado varias maneras y no me sale el ejercicio.

Gracias de antemano  adjunto el código por aquí :

```
public static int contador(Integer[] a, Integer elem)  {
    // Hay que modificar este metodo
    int contador= 0; 
    for(int i =0 ; i<a.length;i++) {
        if(a[i]== elem) {
            contador++;
        }
    }
     
    return contador;  
}
```

Comment: tu metodo debe recibir un tipo de dato primitivo osea public static int contador(int[]a,int elem),Integer es una clase por eso no te copila

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El código esta bien, quizás tu error esta en los parámetros que le estas pasando cuando llamas a la función

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Your code here!
        
        Integer a [] = {1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,5,5};
        
        int result = contador(a, 5);
        
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    
    public static int contador(Integer[] a, Integer elem)  {
        // Hay que modificar este metodo
         int contador= 0; 
        for(int i =0 ; i<a.length;i++) {
             if(a[i]== elem) {
                 contador++;
             }
        }
 
    return contador;  
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, es muy importante revisar [ask] , hay que agregar lo esencial de los enlaces, de otra forma si el enlace deja de servir, la respuesta también, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Me temo que al hacer

```
if(a[i]== elem)
```

Estás comparando objetos y no el contenido de los objetos. Estás comprobando si la referencia al objeto que hay en `a[i]` es la misma que `elem` y obviamente son objetos (instancias) distintas, así que la condición no se va a cumplir nunca y contador se quedará a cero.

Lo que tienes que hacer es comparar el valor entero del objeto y eso lo puedes hacer de varias formas. Por ejemplo:

```
if(a[i].intValue() == elem.intValue())
```

Comparas los valores enteros de cada uno de los objetos.

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar este tipo de elementos debes usar la funcion equals, si utilizas == estas comparando la direccion de memoria.

```
if(a[i].equals(elem))
```

Comment: equals solo se usa para comparar datos de tipo cadena(String)

Comment: @Dramaturgo equals se utiliza para comparar cualquier tipo de objetos y o tipos basicos.

Answer (score 0):

La diferencia sustancial es que, en JAVA, int es un tipo primitivo, no un objeto, mientras que Integer es un objeto o una Clase.

Dicho en lenguaje coloquial: un int es un número, y un Integer es un puntero que hace referencia a una clase que contiene un entero. O... más coloquial todavía: un Integer es una caja, y un int es lo que hay dentro de esa caja.

```
public static int contador(int[] a,int elem)  {
    // Hay que modificar este metodo
    int contador= 0; 
    for(int i =0 ; i<a.length;i++) {
        if(a[i]== elem) {
            contador++;
        }
    }
     
    return contador;  
}
```